# Which jars are required for Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I'm playing around with including Scala in my Java project.

I noticed that IntelliJ includes all of the following jars (extracted) in the generated runnable jar artifact:

```
scala-library-2.12.2.jar
scala-library-2.12.2-sources.jar
scala-reflect-2.12.2.jar
scala-reflect-2.12.2-sources.jar
```

**Ignoring IDEs or build tools**, I am curious as to whether all of these jars are actually required for running code that includes portions written in the Scala language.

I assume that, if I don't use any of the Scala libraries contained in these jars, compiled Scala code can actually run without them (I'm not claiming that it's a good idea - just curious).

So, my question is, which jars are required for what functionality and whether I should ALWAYS include all four jars in any application that uses Scala code.

To clarify, my question is only related to running the code, not building it.

Comment: Scala library is required. Scala reflect is the reflection library that may be required. The other two aren't technically required (they may need to be shipped as per the redistribution agreement) Scala library is always needed. Scala reflect only I'd you're using reflection, although you don't need to export them with the jar at all really if you are just talking about running the" binaries"

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli "Scala library" is scala-library-2.12.2.jar, "Scala reflect" is scala-reflect-2.12.2.jar, "the other two" are the sources? Under what circumstance would the sources be required for running the code?

Comment: @stepanian For **running**, they are not; for step-by-step debugging though...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You mean debugging in production? If I'm using my IDE for debugging in production, which has the sources, then I'm OK, right?

Comment: Yes the other two are the source ones.  The source is never required to run, but it is often required by the licensing / redistribution agreement.  I use the term "required" a bit loosely though. Technically no jar files need to be repackaged like that because they can simply be extracted with the jar itself.

Comment: If your project is written with some Scala you will either need the  scala-library-2.12.jar packaged or extracted with your project. That's why I say not technically required because if you choose to extract your dependencies then you won't get a nice Scala jar dependency included in your Scala project but instead you will have the class files from that library included (not the entire jar). But I think what you are asking is which jar files code is actually being utilized, which agan is likely only the scala-library one in all projects. Let me know if that doesn't make sense I can restate it

Comment: Got it. Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: Posting on mobile was gonna make it a quick answer but since it seemed to turn informative I did post the answer. Hope you found it helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick Summary

The scala-library-2.12.2.jar is always "required".  The Scala scala-reflect-2.12.2.jar  is only required for projects that utilize reflection.  The other two are exactly the same but with the source code also included in the package, those are never required to run the code.

A bit of clarification, technically the answer is none of those jars are required to run the code.  This is because you do not technically need your dependencies to be packaged in jars inside your jar. Instead you can just choose to export the necessary class files with your project. However I think that's somewhat pedantic and a bit beyond what you're asking.

Also, be careful with the term "required" because often certain jar files are required to be repackaged as part of a licensing or redistribution agreement. This is not a technical requirement but rather a legal one.

Comment: So, what you mean by the second paragraph is that, if you really want to reduce the size of your runnable code, you can include the class files of only the portions of the library that you are using and not the whole jar (or extracted jar).

Comment: Yes although it's not like you pick out the specific class files yourself (although you could).  Most IDEs will give you the option to extract your dependencies on export which will go through your projects library and only extract the class files needed. If you notice in the comments above talking  about debugging. If you export the entire jar files (with source) you can actually put break points and debug marks in your 3rd party dependencies if you extract the full source jar. This would be something you couldn't do with your dependencies extracted

Comment: Your welcome but I just want to make a point here because I think I might have came off incorrectly.  When I said it only extracts the class files needed I wasn't referring to the jar dependency being specifically picked apart (as in this class but not that class from the same dependency). What I was trying to say is that the class files themselves get extract into your project individually, not as a compressed jar file.  I didn't intend to say that the IDE selectively picks the classes based on what you actually use, just that the class files are included without the jar

Comment: As an interesting side note, Java SE explicitly forbids you splitting apart the Java SE library like that - it's against their TOS

Comment: Yes, you meant that the library is included in exploded form (as class files rather than jars). Yes, that's what IntelliJ did. I put extracted in parenthesis in my original question. I deleted my confusing comment.